# Embed part of website

Tags: html, iframe, embed

I want to embed just this part on my website. How do I do that? I have tried with iframe and it shows me the whole page I just want the table!

[image]

Comment: Unless the part of the page you want is itself embedded in an iframe, you probably won't be able to separate it out and embed it without some sort of external extraction or parsing process.

Comment: Do you know the id of the div the table is in?

Answer (score 9):

If you do know the id of the div the table is in you can do something like this

HTML

```
<div id="PlaceToPutTable"></div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="urlofpagewithtableonit.html" style="display:hidden;"></iframe>
```

JavaScript

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
var div = document.getElementById("PlaceToPutTable");
div.innerHTML = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById("KnowDivName").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can put the part of an external website starting at some id into an iframe, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/TZPem/). Or you can put an iframe into a div like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CnMCV/).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste html code like this

```html
<iframe width="500" height="300" style="border:none;" src="https://www.rowshare.com/embed/5ff17f44bcb240e0be061e26c0aca207"></iframe>
```

When embedding a table in a website, automatic update can be a challenge. I'd like to propose an alternative tool called RowShare, that allows an automatic update. I explained about this in an article that I wrote. Please feel free to take a look at it: https://www.rowshare.com/blog/en/2017/10/10/How-to-Embed-Tables-in-Your-Website

Astaeka