# How to Embed Part of a Website by Tag Name in Opera Extension

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, opera-extension

**EDIT**: 
I found out that the problem has to do with not having access to the elements inside an iframe without a specific API or something like that. It has been solved.

I need to embed the image of the [Astronomy Picture of the Day](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html) website. Here is the html that I have now:

```
<head>
<style>
    body, html {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    iframe {
        border: none;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="600px" 
src="https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html"></iframe>
    <div id="PlaceToPutTable"></div>
    <script src="panel.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the JavaScript that I have now:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
var div = document.getElementById("PlaceToPutTable");
div.innerHTML = 
iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1];
```

I have tried using `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementByTagName("img")[0]` with and without `.innerHTML` following it. 
I am using this as an Opera Sidebar Extension, so I keep getting this error when adding `.innerHTML`: `Uncaught type error: cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undifined`.

I got this code by manipulating the code I got at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018379/embed-part-of-website), but the Astronomy Picture of the Day image does not include an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

> The undefined property indicates that a variable has not been assigned
>   a value.

You are not getting anything from there.

---

I would suggest you to debug a bit your code. First of all it seems like this is not getting anything `iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("a")[1]` so you should first debug it to see if it contains the element you are looking for.

So you should debug with a console log and see what this gets:

```
console.log(iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("img"));
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: When I do this the console gives this error: Uncaught TypeError: iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementByTagName is not a function.

Comment: Seems like a typo. It's getElementsByTagName (Notice the plural on Elements). Editing now sorry